# Freeze after splash screen upon startup

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, freeze, drive

I've got a dual boot with Windows 10.

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu today and all went pretty well, rebooted a few times, no problem. Then I opened some of the other partitions/drives and they appeared on my desktop. I tried to delete them but was unable to. Googled how to get rid of them and it said to unmount them, that it wouldn't do any harm. So I did that, and it seems that that caused it to get stuck after the loading/splash screen.

I think I tried to re-mount via Advanced Options in the Grub menu but I have no clue if I did the right thing. I've never used Linux before.

Content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
# 
# [file system] [mount point] [type] [options] [dump] [pass]
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=249483ee-09dc-43d9-956d-a490fb1b5101 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /home was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=44fc1623-3db6-4a9e-99bb-103c9460565e /home ext4 defaults 0 2
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=6cdb970e-de25-42e2-9f07-f3fb442f0d44 none swap sw 0 0
```

It doesn't actually look like the issue is the partitions. Did a clean install, updated everything, installed Spotify, Discord, Atom and installed Ruby. Rebooted and it freezes all the same. I also added a 1920x1200 screen resolution using xrandr, but that's about everything.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the contents of the file `/etc/fstab` as these partitions probably still get mounted there. if the GUI doesn't work, press [Ctrl][Alt][F1] and log into text mode only and to `cat /etc/fstab`, then type everything exactly as it is in your question.

Comment: Added it in. Might not be very readable but I tried.

Comment: Edited for readability, but going to sleep now.  Did you delete partition 5, 6 or 7 on your second disk?

Comment: It might have been sdb7, /home. I don't quite remember though.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have enough rep to open a chat room and due some deeper digging.  I understood it worked originally without freezing and only froze after you deleted partitions, but now it freezes after the first reboot?  Can you still log into the console ([Ctrl][Alt][F1]?

Comment: The culprit seems to be that I added these lines to ~/.profile (with the command `gedit ~/.profile`):
`sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"` (and some of the settings from `cvt 1920 1200`
`sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1920x1200_60.00"`
These commands works just fine when I use them manually and then select it in the display settings. Everything's fine. It said I could add them to profile for them to be saved, but clearly that's causing the machine to hang. Could it be that the extra `sudo` I added there is an issue?

Comment: Removing sudo magically worked. God knows why and why this isn't explained.

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't related to partitions (at least not that based on what I've found).

My first monitor would originally show at a resolution of 1024x784 or whatever it was, whereas it should be 1920x1200. I applied these settings with xrandr and all was fine, looked the way I wanted it to, and the website I got it from told me to add these lines to ~/.profile using `gedit ~/.profile`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1920x1200_60.00"
```

But I had `sudo` in front of the `xrandr` command. That's what caused it to freeze on startup. Removing the `sudo` made it automatically switch to this correct resolution upon startup, and also made it work again.

Comment: **+1** for finding the solution yourself.